# extern NSString not accessible since Swift 2.2

Tags: xcode, swift

Since the update to Xcode 7.3 with Swift 2.2 I am not able to access variables from an external Objective-C Library.

Since today I was able to access this variables:

```
extern NSString* const DEFAULT_URL;
```

This is defined in an Objective-C Header file from a precompiled .a framework.

In my swift code I only had to call `DEFAULT_URL`.

Since Swift 2.2 I get the following errror:

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'DEFAULT_URL'
```

I am able to access the classes and methods of this framework, but I can't access `extern NSStrings`.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I have updated the issue, the extern is defined in a obj-c header file. I have also build a bridging header.

Comment: No, but I have added this now, but this doesn't change anything.

Comment: I have same issue.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

@patrickS I had this for a silly reason, my extern const was defined inside an @interface in my .h file. This seems to have made it private to Swift code with this version of XCode / Clang. It applies to all extern consts not just NSString *.

e.g.

```
//In Foo.h
extern const int kBlah

@interface Foo
...
@end
```

instead of

```
//In Foo.h
@interface Foo
extern const int kBlah
...
@end
```

Comment: the same goes for typedef

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and as in the question, the ext strings were in my case in a dependency-managed (*cough* pod *cough*) third party library. So I could not easily move them around without messing everything up in the long run.

I found two solutions:

1. copy-paste the ext declaration to (the bottom of) your bridging
   header
2. write your own static helper class in objective c that
   provides the ext strings as class methods (and make this static helper available to Swift)

I leave it up to you which of the two solutions you deem less hacky (I went with solution 1, as I am lazy).