# Swift 2.2 | constants define inside @interface and @end keyword are not accessible in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift2

After Xcode 7.3 and swift 2.2 my constants define inside @interface and @end keyword are not accessible in swift, may be swift mark them private or something like that.

How I can make my constants publicaly available in swift code.

```
// Constants.h
@interface Test
    extern NSString * const BASE_URL;
@end

// Constants.m
@implementation Test
    NSString * const BASE_URL=@"http://my-server.com/";
@end
```

Someone suggest [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36148598/extern-nsstring-not-accessible-since-swift-2-2/36155592#36155592) to take the constant out from @interface to make it visible, but I am not sure of the consequences of this solution.

Any idea how to make it fix properly.

Comment: Why in the world would you do that in the first place?